# Disabling "Show notifications" isn't always working

Tags: notifications, settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4

This scenario happens specifically on an unrooted/original SGS4 4.3 with the Glovebox app. See screenshots. I haven't encountered such a problem up until now.

**Any idea why the notification is show even though it shouldn't?**

Enabling and disabling the checkbox again does the trick and removes the notification - until the next time it is show.

Notification:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Notification]

App info:

[image: IMG: App info]

Comment: maybe it hasn't installed correctly?